# How do I set the Subclipse/Eclipse date format on OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, subclipse

Using the Subclipse plugin (1.4.5) for Eclipse (3.4.1, OS X) adds some subversion metadata to the file navigator pane, including the modified date. Unfortunately this date is in m/d/y format, when I would prefer it to be in d/m/y.

Subclipse may be using Eclipse for the date formatting, but I don't recall having seen any other instances of m/d/y (other date locations in Eclipse all seem to include the full month name). In any case I haven't been able to find a way of setting the format in either Eclipse or Subclipse settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. System Preferences > International > Language.
2. Click 'Edit List'
3. Check 'Australian English'
4. Click OK
5. Restart Eclipse

Comment: Fixed based on that page: System Preferences > International > Language.
- Click 'Edit List' > Check 'Australian English' > OK; restart Eclipse.
Thanks